# Is is possible control keyboard type in flutter inappwebview?

Tags: flutter, webview, keyboard

I am developing flutter app.

This app has webview using inappwebview package.

(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

So I want to handle keyboard type like number type.

I can't find how to control this.

Is it possible to show keyboard type what I intend?

Answer (score 0):

you can control keyboard type and type of input in webview

import this file

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

use this inside TextFormField

for digits only

```
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]
```

or you can use regex to get custom inputs, this one is for accepting string characters only :

```
inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"))]
```

and add keyboard types

`keyboardType: TextInputType.number`   or   `keyboardType: TextInputType.name,`

Example 1:

```
TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]
)
```

Example 2 (regex):

```
TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
    inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"))],
)
```

Comment: Thanks you. I did not explain well. Sorry. My intend was KeyboardType in "WebView".

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286328/flutter-webview-text-input-gets-hidden-by-soft-keyboard